# Implementing soft delete on database

Tags: sqlite, filter, sql-delete

I have an SQLite database and I'm moving to a soft delete approach which is:

- Add a `delete` field to every table. This field can either be set to 0 (not-deleted) or 1 (deleted)
- Transform every `DELETE` query into an `UPDATE` one, which sets the delete flag to 1
- Modify every `SELECT` query by adding the `AND delete = 0` condition to pickup only the non-deleted records

**The new database schema**

Here the `card` table:

```
+------------+---------+-----------+
| id         | name    | deleted   |
+------------+---------+-----------+
```

Here the `tag` table:

```
+------------+---------+-----------+
| id         | name    | deleted   |
+------------+---------+-----------+
```

Here the `cardtag` table:

```
+------------+---------+-----------+
| cardid     | tagid   | deleted   |
+------------+---------+-----------+
```

`cardtag.cardid` and `cardtag.tagid` are respectively foreign keys for `card.id` and `tag.id`

As you can see `cardtag` is the classic relationship table that assigns multiple tags to the cards

**Queries I still need to modify**

I managed to port almost all queries to the soft-delete approach (very trivial) except for the following:

**Query to retrieve a card and associated list of tags by `card.id`**

```
SELECT c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ct.tagid) FROM cards as c LEFT JOIN cardtag as ct ON c.id = ct.cardid WHERE c.id = ? GROUP BY c.id;
```

This query should be modified to be aware of the `deleted` flag on the `tag` and `cardtag` tables and act accordingly

**Query to retrieve all cards and associated list of tags by providing a [list_of_comma_separated_tag_ids]**

```
SELECT c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ct.tagid) FROM cards as c LEFT JOIN cardtag as ct ON c.id = ct.cardid LEFT JOIN tags as t ON t.id = ct.tagid AND t.id IN ([list_of_comma_separated_tag_ids]) GROUP BY c.id HAVING COUNT(ct.tagid) >= COUNT(t.id) AND COUNT(t.id) = [list_of_comma_separated_tag_ids.length] AND c.deleted = 0
```

This query should be modified to be aware of the `deleted` flag on the `tag` and `cardtag` tables and act accordingly

This last query works by looking at the provided list of tag IDs and picks all the cards that have those tags associated to them (they may have even other tags of course). To rephrase: the query selects all the cards that have at least all the tag ids provided in input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this in your queries is to not change the queries at all, and to create [views](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) that make the tables look like they were before:

```
CREATE VIEW card_view AS SELECT id, name FROM card_actual WHERE deleted = 0;
```

(It would also be possible to create [INSTEAD OF DELETE triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) on the views.)

Comment: I like the view approach but I'd like to avoid it

Answer (score 2):

You could use `AND` in your `JOIN` part

First Query

```
SELECT c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ct.tagid) FROM cards as c LEFT JOIN cardtag as ct ON c.id = ct.cardid AND ct.deleted != 1 WHERE c.id = ? GROUP BY c.id;
```

Second Query

```
SELECT c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ct.tagid) FROM cards as c LEFT JOIN cardtag as ct ON c.id = ct.cardid AND ct.deleted != 1 LEFT JOIN tags as t ON t.id = ct.tagid AND t.deleted != 1 AND t.id IN ([list_of_comma_separated_tag_ids]) GROUP BY c.id HAVING COUNT(ct.tagid) >= COUNT(t.id) AND COUNT(t.id) = [list_of_comma_separated_tag_ids.length] AND c.deleted = 0
```

Comment: thanks. My gut feeling tells me that I also have to take into account the deleted flag in the tag table. Why such flag is not needed at all? I mean, if such flag is set then the tag has been removed altogether

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini What i wrote is just an example of what you could use. Using the same trick on the other join is no problem at all.

Comment: yes thanks but I'm not familiar with the left join and ON statement so it's not obvious to me where to place those extra conditions.. could you show to me how to do it?

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini Updated the query.

Comment: thanks! upvoted! and for the first one? I'll accept the answer

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini Updated the answer again. Besides giving you the answer I suggest trying to understand the answer. By giving you just one of the two queries You should've been able to make the other one.